# Invalid syntax error for every command in python

Tags: python

I'm using the python command line to install tensorflow, following the tutorial here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows

I'm on windows 10, installed python 3.7.8, and got to step 2, where I have to paste
"python -m venv --system-site-packages .\venv" into the command line, and I get the error pictured here, invalid syntax

[image: the error pictured here, invalid syntax].

Any command I paste into python always points to the second parameter and says that it has invalid syntax. This has happened before when trying to run programs and earlier I ended up just running them directly instead of using the command line.

Comment: You shouldn't be running that in a python shell, it has to run on command line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to run Python from inside its own shell!

Quit the shell and invoke Python as you want, or change your editor's invocation such that it works the way you want.